# How to remove click event from "No file chosen" which appears next to file upload button

Tags: html, css

I have a file upload button and by default the text is present as "No file Chosen" to it and clicking on this text opens up the explorer to upload the file which is kind of same functionality as the button itself. I am looking to remove this click functionality from the text.

Also, is it a normal behavior happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite browser dependent, but what you're describing is a file upload component. It's created by the browser for your `<input>` tag. It's all perfectly standard and normal. Just like `<input type="text" />` will render a text box, `<input type="file" />` renders button + text.

Using CSS you may hide the text completely, by setting its `width` to cut off the text.

You can also cover it with another element.

Example of both:

```css
#hide-text {
  width: 6.5em;
}
#cover-text + div {
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
  right: -5.5em;
  top: -1.2em;
  height: 1em;
  width: 6.7em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
Hide
<br />
<input id="hide-text" type=file />
<br/>Cover
<br />
<input id="cover-text" type=file />
<div>
</div>
</div>
```

(Uncomment the border to see what the `div` is actually doing)

Comment: Yeah, I know I can hide the text by giving the width same as of the button itself which will remove the text but is there anyway I can eliminate the click event from the default text? and is it behaving normally??

Comment: Marked your answer as I felt that your answer does fulfills what I am looking for

Comment: It is normal, since as far as the browser is concerned this is **one** element, not two. The second option I gave does not really eliminate the click handler from the text, but it generates the same effect.